# How Does Char Variable Work in C

Tags: c

What I am trying to accomplish is prompting the user with the question of do they want to run the program again. They either type y or n. If y, it reruns the program. If no, it stops the program. Anything other than those two will prompt an error and ask the question again. I'm used to C# where strings are not complicated, but in C, I guess there technically isn't strings, so we have to use either char arrays or char pointers. I've tried both, none that work that way I want, but I'm probably the problem. This is what I have.

```
char answer[1] = "a";

while (strcmp(answer, "y") != 0 || strcmp(answer, "n") != 0)
{
    printf ("\n\nWould you like to run the program again? Type y or n. Then, hit Enter.");
    scanf ("%c", answer);

    if (strcmp(answer, "y") == 0)
    {
        main();
    }
    else if (strcmp(answer, "n") == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf ("\nERROR: Invalid input was provided. Your answer must be either y or n. Hit Enter to continue.");
        F = getchar();
        while ((getchar()) != F && EOF != '\n');
    }
}
```

I have other while loops similar to this that work as expected, but use a float. So I'm assuming the problem is me using char here. What happens right now is that it doesn't even prompt the user for the question. It just asks the question and shows the error right afterwards. I'm sure there are other things wrong with this code, but since I can't get the prompt to work, I cannot test the rest of it yet.

Comment: A loop is more suited for "run-again" problems on small code.. otherwise you might run out of stack space. But nevermind..

Comment: if you want `c` to be considered a single `char`, you should write `'c'` not `"c"`

Comment: `while (strcmp(answer, "y") != 0 || strcmp(answer, "n") != 0)` ... this will always be true since if one side == 0, the other cannot; perhaps replacing `||` with `&&` will get you what you're looking for. Beyond that, your code as written is not dealing with chars, it's dealing with C strings.

Comment: `char answer[1] = "a";` this is horrible. You should seriously RTFM/a intro to C, and then come back.

Comment: Additionally, you're calling `main()` if the answer == "y"... there's _no_ value (and possibly some harm) in calling main recursively here! Refactor away the recursion and only make recursive calls for things that either require recursion or, at a minimum, have a finite depth of recursion and recursion helps solve the problem.

Comment: @ThorX89 If you didn't understand the fact that from what I wrote that I didn't understand C, then you should SERIOUSLY take in intro class to understanding humans and how not to be a dick 101.

Comment: @mah Yeah, I really didn't think that main() would actually work. Just put it there for the time being since I couldn't even get to that part yet, since before that wasn't working, but thanks for the input. Also, changing it to && still kept the problem.

Comment: Is it on purpose that you put `c` instead of `&c` in the `scanf()`?

Comment: Using `char` arrays as strings is how C handles text input and output. However, in order for it to work, you always need space for at least one more character at the end of the string which is set to `'\0'`, called the terminating NULL-character. This denotes the end of the string. So if you want to store `"a"` in a `char`-array, you need at least an array of 2 `char`s. But as already mentioned by others, you can also use a single `char` instead of string-based comparison to solve this problem.

Comment: The original code tried to treat `answer` as a string in the `strcmp()` calls, but it isn't a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. It is by no means the only way to do it, but I think it accomplishes what you want. You should not call the main function recursively.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void run_program()
{
    printf("program was run.");
}

int main() {
    char answer[2] = "y\0";
    int dump;    

    do {

        if (answer[0] == 'y')
        {
            run_program(); /* Not main, don't call main recursively. */
        }

        printf ("\n\nWould you like to run the program again? Type y or n. Then, hit Enter.\n");
        scanf ("%1s", answer);

        /* Dump all other characters on the input buffer to
           prevent continuous reading old characters if a user
           types more than one, as suggested by ThorX89. */
        while((dump=getchar())!='\n' && dump!=EOF); 

        if (answer[0] != 'n' && answer[0] != 'y')
        {
            printf ("Please enter either y or n\n");
        }

    } while (answer[0] != 'n');

    return 0;
}
```

Using %s instead of %c, reads in the new line so that the new line character is not in the stdin buffer which would become answer then next time scanf was called.

The run_program function is just a function where you would put your program's logic. You can call it whatever you want. I did this to separate out the menu logic from the logic of the actual program.

Comment: Changing %c to %s seemed to solve the problem. Thanks. Also, what's the problem with calling main recursively? It still works. And the way you rewrote it, if I answered y, it wouldn't actually rerun the program. It would just print program was run.

Comment: Ah, I see, I should clarify. The run program function was just a method I made which is where you should write the logic for your program. You can call that function whatever you want.

Calling main recursively will complicate your logic unnecessarily, and, additionally, if you go deep enough on the call stack you will run out of stack space which can cause a...wait for it....StackOverflow!

Comment: Note that the original code and this code both have the same problem in slightly different forms.  You can't use `char answer;` or `char answer[1];` as a string because there isn't enough space for a character and the terminating null byte.  The variable needs to be at least `char answer[2];` (with the corresponding removal of an `&` when it is passed to `scanf()`), and the format string should be `"%1s"` to prevent buffer overflows.  If the user types "You must be kidding me" in response to your prompt, then `scanf()` will trigger a stack overflow.

Comment: I see what you mean about the buffer overflow. I've updated the answer accordingly. @ThorX89, when you say dangerous, are you referring to a security vulnerability?

Comment: @Tyler Fleming Cloutier He's declared answer as a char, and is reading into it a string of unknown length. Seems like a security vulnerability and a potential for a segfault to me.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a light weight `getchar()` instead of the heavy `scanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int c;  /* Note getchar returns int because it must handle EOF as well. */   

for (;;) {
    printf ("Enter y or n\n");
    c = getchar();
    switch (c) {
    case 'y': ...
        break;
    case 'n': ...
        break:
    case EOF:
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The advantage of `scanf()` is that it can skip white space if you use a leading space in the format (`" %c"`).  Your code as shown will prompt when it gets the newline, and then again for the next character.

Comment: @Jens Using the c = getchar() didn't solve the problem. I continued to use the if statements with the while statement I had before, but I don't think using the switch statement would have changed that. I don't understand why int c can store characters.

Comment: @user2781018 char is basically an integer type. You use it most frequently to store characters, but you can use it to store small numbers, too. In C, smaller integer types can be automatically promoted to a larger one.  `getchar` deals with a larger type, because it must have space to store, among others the EOF special signal. The whole width of the char is already taken up by letters (mostly).

Comment: if you don't want the character to be echoed, use `getch` instead of `getchar`. Then you can manually use `putch` or whatever to display it when they press n or y.

Answer (score 1):

- `"a"` is a string literal == `char id[2]={'a','\0'} //Strings are
  char arrays terminated by zero, in C`
- `'a'` is a char literal
- `strcmp` is just "compare each char in two strings, until you hit '\0'"
- `scanf ("%c", ___);` expect an address to write to as the second
  argument. Functions in C cannot modify their arguments (they don't
  have access to them--they get their own local copy) unless they have
  a memory address. You need to put `&answer` in there.

Jens has already basically answered the question, you most likely want to use `getchar` so that you can detect `EOF` easily. Unlike `scanf("%c",...)`, `getchar` will not skip spaces, and I believe both versions will leave you with the unprocessed rest of the input line (a newline character (`'\n'`) at least) after each `getchar`. You might want to something like

```
int dump;
while((dump=getchar())!='\n' && dump!=EOF) {};
```

So that you discard the rest of the line once you've read your first character of it.
Otherwise, the next `getchar` will get the next unprocessed character of the same line. ('\n' if the line was a single letter).

Answer (score -1):

Well, you are comparing two strings instead of characters.
If you want to compare two character you have to follow this syntax:

```
char c;
scanf("%c",&c);

if(c == 'y')
    //do something
else
    //do nothing
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in `char c = '';` and undefined behavior in `fflush(stdin);`.

Comment: Remember: `fflush(stdin)` _is_ defined behaviour on Windows; it isn't defined behaviour elsewhere.